# Magetno: How to show different product options on product list page

Tags: magento, product

I have a website with products of different weights and price.

eg.  Product Name : Potato
      5KG : Rs. 50
      1KG : Rs. 25
      500 gms :  Rs 15

On product list page I want to show Potato picture and when user hovers it should show all three options to choose from.

attached is the image for same:
[product display screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajvVJ.png)

in above screen shot, when user hovers over product, two options are shown with weight and price. He can select any of those to cart.

Comment: Can you be more specific of your question? Can't understand what exactly do you want. Also, you can show the image in the question.

Comment: I am new here, doesn't allow me to add image to question. i have updated the question. please check image, you will know what i am looking for.